# Updating vsDoc to 1.5 breaks all javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-2010

I'm having some difficulty with what seems to be the simplest of operations.

In visual studio, when I change vsDoc from 1.4.1 to 1.5, javascript on the page no longer works.  (Visual Studio 2010)

The original (that works) is like this:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link type="text/css" href="css/excite-bike/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And everything is fine, intellisense is fine, javascript is fine.  Everything is good to go.

However, when I reference the newer vsDoc file (obtained from [ajax.aspnetcdn.com](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5-vsdoc.js) )

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link type="text/css" href="css/excite-bike/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />    

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.5-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The page doesn't load properly and firebug shows the following errors:

```
class2type is not defined
rootjQuery is not defined
```

Both errors are apparently stemming from the vsdoc file line 67

I feel like I'm missing something terribly obvious and I hope someone can fill me in.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `-vsdoc` is not intended to be included in your actual page, just in the files you need intellisense in.  For your use, just rename:

```
 Scripts/jquery-1.5-vsdoc.js
```

to

```
 Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js
```

and then *remove* that `-vsdoc.js` `<script>` block from the page.  Visual studio will *automatically* search for the `-vsdoc.js` of any local JavaScript file you're including default.  It need not be included in the page explicitly...that'll actually lead to issues like you're seeing, since it defines the same empty functions (and not all the needed variables).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Frankly I have no idea how I got the idea that I needed to directly reference the vsdoc file. I just now went and re-read the Scott Gu blog post about vsdoc in vsstudio 2008 and clearly I was just reading sentences that just don't exist! :) I'm going to go ahead and blame my mistake on working at 6am on a Sunday.  Thanks again!

Comment: But why he got this problem only with new vsdoc file? and I didn't get what the change 1.5 to 1.5.1 should do. Can you explain it to me please?