# MVC3 JQuery getJSON returns error s is undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a function calling a controller method in MVC3.

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("LoadCitiesByProvince", "Property")', { id: 1}, function (msg) {
    alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
});
```

The final rendered Javascript:

```
$.getJSON('/MySite/Property/LoadCitiesByProvince', { id: 1 }, function (msg) {
alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
});
```

Firebug reports the following error:

```
s is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

callbackContext = s.context || s,
```

When I debug my controller method is never hit. I have triple checked the controller method even calling it manually via the url in my browser (in whitch case it works as expected). This is my controller method:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult LoadCitiesByProvince(string id)
{
    var modelList = this.GetCities(Convert.ToInt32(id));

    var modelData = modelList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = m.Description,
        Value = m.Id.ToString(),

    });

    return Json(modelData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

At this point all I want to see is my controller method being hit and data coming back.

Comment: Please post the JS as returned to the browser.

Comment: I added the rendered JS as requested.

Comment: It looks fine to me.  Are you sure that the problem is related to the getJSON call?  Do you not get this error if you comment it out?

Comment: If you're seeing that error in Firebug, it's because you have an error somewhere else on your page.  Your getJSON call is just fine.

Comment: @BrentAnderson Thanks, that helped me to look in the right place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the jquery vsdoc javascript file included with MVC3. It causes this error. Simply Changing the javascript include line:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is a link to a question about this issue:

[Updating vsDoc to 1.5 breaks all javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611419/updating-vsdoc-to-1-5-breaks-all-javascript)